# Acessar variáveis de config.php

Tags: php, orientação-a-objetos, classes, require

Eu sou iniciante em php e estou com um problema, eu tenho uma arquivo config.php dessa maneira:

```
<?php
$config['dbHostname'] = 'localhost';
$config['dbUser'] = 'teste';
$config['dbPassword'] = 'passteste';
```

Porem tenho uma classe com funções de conexão e manipulação do banco de dados que utilizariam essas variáveis do `config.php` porém não consegui acessa-las de maneira alguma, por favor alguem poderia me ajudar?

Comment: Pessoal me desculpem mas a intenção é eu ter um arquivo apenas com configurações, depois em outra classe eu farei a conexão e manipulação de dados, não fazer a conexão no mesmo php que as configurações

Comment: O exemplo é você ter um arquivo separado realmente, não tem lógica fazer no mesmo arquivo e ai utilizar tal arquivo (com include ou require) para dispor a vários arquivos que vão utilizar conexão com banco de dados ... Mas, a sua dúvida não era como ler tal arquivo com a variavel Array $config ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seria uma das formas, nesse caso pelo construtor da classe.

```
<?php

$config['dbHostname'] = 'localhost';
$config['dbUser'] = 'teste';
$config['dbPassword'] = 'passteste';

class Conexao
{
    private $pdo;
    public function __construct($config){
        $this->pdo = 
            new PDO("mysql:dbname=generics;host=".$config['dbHostname'], $config['dbUser'], $config['dbPassword']);
    }
}


$conexao = new Conexao($config);

?>
```

Comment: Embora ele seja iniciante, é sempre bom ensinar métodos seguros de conexão, mas o ideal seria mostrar a ele o mysqli primeiro. E a variavel $config ja é uma array, especificar o atributo da array por nome so acupa espaço no código *-* creio que o ideal seria simplificar $config[0,1,2]...

Comment: Pessoal me desculpem mas a intenção é eu ter um arquivo apenas com configurações, depois em outra classe eu farei a conexão e manipulação de dados, não fazer a conexão no mesmo php que as configurações

Comment: Caro G. Foratini, você pode fazer um include desse trecho para que seja visto nos arquivos que tu vai utilizar tal configuração, no meu exemplo (como disse exemplo) eu quis que você entendesse a forma trivial para passar para uma classe, porque sua questão foi essa como ler as configurações de um $config que é um variavel do tipo Array para as minhas classes.  Na questão de utilizar Mysqli ou PDO o material tem no próprio site (www.php.net). Sobre ocupar espaço, não vejo problema em utilizar um $config do tipo Array, que é uma coisa que os frameworks tem de monte ...

Comment: Ahh sim entendi agora, muito obrigado acabei me expressando mal valeu ;)

Answer (score 1):

Você pode acessar ela declarando a variável no início da função com a keyword `global`

```
public function mostrar1()
{
    global $txt;
    echo $txt;
}
```

Ou utilizar a super-global `$GLOBALS`

```
public function mostrar2()
{
    $msg = $GLOBALS['txt'];
    echo $msg;
}
```

Exemplo rodando http://ideone.com/ek9ACf

Lembrando que se você está programando utilizando classes não é muito recomendado utilizar variáveis globais pois as mesmas podem causar conflitos, se for utilizá-las copie os dados dela que te interessam e remova ela do escopo global.

```
class Config
{
    /**
     * Configurações
     */
    var $safeconfig;

    public function __construct()
    {
        global $config;

        $this->safeconfig = $config;
        unset($config);
    }

    /**
     * Adicione aqui alguns setters e getters
     * para ter acesso as configurações
     */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Uma forma simplificada para fazer isso apenas com config.php seria:

```
<?php
    $config['dbHostname'] = 'localhost';
    $config['dbUser'] = 'teste';
    $config['dbPassword'] = 'passteste';
    $config['dbSchema'] = 'baseteste';
    
    $mysqli = new mysqli($config['dbHostname'],  $config['dbUser'], $config['dbPassword'], $config['dbSchema']);

    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
       printf("Falha na conexão: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
       exit();
    }
```

Qualquer duvida sobre utilização da função mysqli só olhar na [documentação oficial](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php)

Answer (score 0):

Olá use essa seguinte conexão, provavelmente você não esta selecionando o banco de dados use a minha conexão mas coloque o nome do seu banco de dados

```
<?php 
$servidor = "localhost";
$banco = "NOME DO BANCO DE DADOS AQUI";
$usuario = "teste";
$senha = "passteste";
$conexao = mysql_connect ($servidor, $usuario, $senha);
$conexao = mysql_select_db ("$banco", $conexao);
if (!$conexao) {
echo mysql_error; exit;
}
?>
```

Comment: Verdade mesmo Lucas eu acho que ele não esta selecionando o Bando de dados

Comment: As funções mysql_* foram depreciadas, por favor não poste código que incita o usuário à usá-las.